# partial limits of two sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

let ${a_{n}}$ ${b_{n}}$ be sequences.
$\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_{n}-b_{n})=0$
prove that both seqneces' subsequences' limits are exactly same.

right now I have no clue where should I begin. any suggestion would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What is a partial limit?

Comment: Umberto: searching for 'partial limits' gave me the following: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Partial_limit therefore i assumed it's a correct term (probably not popular), I'm not taking the course in English therefore I don't know the  exact English definitions (hope to link would explain what i mean). To Null: well, basically I tried doing some manipulations using the definition of limit for the series a_n-b_n but didn't have such success

Comment: Two sequences may be divergent, e.g. $a_n = n$ and $b_n = n - \frac1n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ell$ is a partial limit of $\{a_n\}$, there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=\ell$. Now note that
$$
b_{n_k}=a_{n_k}+(b_{n_k}-a_{n_k}).
$$